# phpunit mock does not return assigned value

Tags: mocking, phpunit

I have this code:

```
class TestMe {
    private $params;

    public function __construct($params) {
        $this->params = $params;
    }

    public function one($arg) {
        echo 'one is running ';
        $next = $arg + 1;
        return $this->two($next);
    }

    private function two($arg) {
        echo 'two is running ';
        $next = $arg + 1;
        return $this->three($next);
    }

    private function three($arg) {
        echo 'three is running ';
        return 'original return value';
    }
}

class TestMeTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    private $params = array();

    public function test() {
        $testMeMock = $this->getMockBuilder('TestMe')
            ->setConstructorArgs( array($this->params) )
            ->setMethods( array('two') )
            ->getMock();

        $testMeMock->expects($this->any())
                ->method('two')
                ->will($this->returnArgument(0));

        $result = $testMeMock->one(1);

        $this->assertEquals(2, $result);
    }
}
```

I wrote this with the purpose of testing the argument going into the method 'two', but instead i'm getting the 'original return value' string, and the 'three' method is running.

```
Failed asserting that 'original return value' matches expected 2.
```

How can i test to verify the argument that goes into 'two'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the function that you are trying to mock is `private` and your mock is calling the original function rather than the mocked replacement.  Change the functions to `protected` and your test will work as you intend.

As an aside, it is generally not recommended to test protected/private methods of a class.  As a rule, you should only test the public interface of a class.  If the internal methods are complicated enough to require being mocked, it is a sign that you may want to refactor those into their own class.

http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/881-Testing-Your-Privates.html

This works:

```
class TestMe {
    private $params;

    public function __construct($params) {
        $this->params = $params;
    }

    public function one($arg) {
        echo 'one is running ';
        $next = $arg + 1;
        return $this->two($next);
    }

    protected function two($arg) {
        echo 'two is running ';
        $next = $arg + 1;
        return $this->three($next);
    }

    private function three($arg) {
        echo 'three is running ';
        return 'original return value';
    }
}

class TestMeTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    private $params = array();

    public function test() {
        $testMeMock = $this->getMockBuilder('TestMe')
            ->setConstructorArgs( array($this->params) )
            ->setMethods( array('two') )
            ->getMock();

        $testMeMock->expects($this->any())
                ->method('two')
                ->will($this->returnArgument(0));

        $result = $testMeMock->one(1);

        $this->assertEquals(2, $result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to underline that: Don't mock the classes you are about to test! This is the real error here. If you want to test a private method inside, move that into a separate object with public methods, and insert that object into the original class.